# Posting data to Firebase using a form

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple form with inputs:

```
<body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
            <h2>Add a new Animal</h2>
    <form class="form-group" id="add-animals">
    Species: <input type="text" id="species" class="form-control">
    Name: <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" >
    Age: <input type="text" id="age" class="form-control">
    Last Fed: <input type="date" id="last-fed" class="form-control">
    Last Shed: <input type="date" id="last-shed" class="form-control">
    Diet: <input type="text" id="diet" class="form-control">
    Basking area temperature: <input type="text" id="basking-area-temperature" class="form-control">
    Cold part temperature: <input type="text" id="cold-temperature" class="form-control">
    Humidity: <input type="text" id="humidity" class="form-control">
    Addition Info: <textarea class="form-control" id="additional-info"></textarea>
    <button id="btnCreate" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
    </form>
    <h3>View Current Animals</h3>
    <ol id="animal-list">

    </ol>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBSuC8nqJzLe7d5jKS-_nE15kaI9Y6NIfI",
    authDomain: "repti-care-32176.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://repti-care-32176.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "repti-care-32176",
    storageBucket: "repti-care-32176.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "632910932105"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  const db = firebase.firestore();
  db.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true }); 
</script>
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="./scripts/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

And I want to add new entries to my database when the form is submitted, here is my js:

```
const animalList = document.querySelector('#animal-list');
const form = document.querySelector('#add-animals');


function renderAnimals(doc) {
let li = document.createElement('li');
let name = document.createElement('div');
let species = document.createElement('div');
let age = document.createElement('div');
let last_fed = document.createElement('div');
let last_shed = document.createElement('div');
let diet = document.createElement('div');
let basking_area_temp = document.createElement('div');
let cold_part_temp = document.createElement('div');
let humidity = document.createElement('div');
let additional_info = document.createElement('div');

li.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);
name.textContent = `name: ${doc.data().name}`
species.textContent = `species: ${doc.data().species}`
age.textContent = `age: ${doc.data().age}`
last_fed.textContent = `last fed: ${doc.data().last_fed}`;
last_shed.textContent = `last shed: ${doc.data().last_shed}`;
diet.textContent = `diet: ${doc.data().diet}`;
basking_area_temp.textContent =`basking area temp: ${ doc.data().basking_area_temp}`;
cold_part_temp.textContent =  `cold part temp: ${doc.data().cold_part_temp}`;
humidity.textContent = `humidity: ${doc.data().humidity}`;
additional_info.textContent = `additional info: ${doc.data().additional_info}`;

li.appendChild(species);
li.append(name);
li.append(age);
li.append(last_fed);
li.append(last_shed);
li.append(diet);
li.append(basking_area_temp);
li.append(cold_part_temp);
li.append(humidity);
li.append(additional_info);

animalList.appendChild(li);
}

// getting data from the back end
db.collection('animals').get().then((snapshot) => {
snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
    renderAnimals(doc);
  })
})

// adding data
form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    db.collection('animals').add({
        species: form.species.value,
        name: form.name.value,
        age: form.age.value,
        last_fed: form.last_fed.value,
        last_shed: form.last_shed.value,
        diet: form.diet.value,
        basking_area_temp: form.basking_area_temp.value,
        cold_part_temp: form.cold_part_temp.value,
        humidity: form.humidity.value,
        additional_info: form.additional_info.value

    })
})
```

Currently when I add the information to my form fields it fires off an error:

Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at HTMLFormElement.form.addEventListener (main.js:58)

why is my last_fed object property undefined and how can I fix this so that the data gets posted to the database? For some reasons there happens to be a problem only with the variables that have a "_" sign in them, if I remove them everything works fine

Comment: It's unclear what the relationship is between the error and the *last_fed* property. Why do you think it's undefined? Can you more clearly define what you're attempting to do with this code? The addEventListener comment shows *//adding data* so are you adding data or trying to listen for changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're initializing `form` like this:

```
const form = document.querySelector('#add-animals');
```

And then in the submit-handler you do:

```
species: form.species.value
```

The `form.species` doesn't point to anything. There is nothing in the DOM that allows you to look up the fields in a form by their ID like that.

You'll need to look up each field from the HTML with a query selector. So for this line:

```
species: document.querySelector("species").value
```

Note that this type of problem is easy to troubleshoot once you put a breakpoint in the code that throws an error, and hit it with a breakpoint. From there you can inspect the `form` variable and see that it doesn't have a `species` property.

Comment: Did that and then again it tells me that last_shed is not defined. If that is the case then how come all of the other variables that don't have an underscore get posted like species but the rest are undefined?

Comment: You spelled the input with a `-`: `<input type="date" id="last-fed"`. So that's also what you have to use to get the value: `document.querySelector("last-fed").value`.